# LUVIT DISCORDIA how to get the id of a guild

Tags: lua, luvit

I want to get the id of the guild when someone types +guildid, so that i can use it for stuff later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO, turns out i can just do this `local <string name> = message.member.guild.id`